# PHP Insert new directory between parent and subdirectory

Tags: php, directory, rename

I have a parent directory:

```
"path/to/dir"
```

Inside this parent directory I have several subdirectories:

```
"dir/subA"
"dir/subB"
"dir/subC"
```

I would like to move all these subdirectories into an intermediary directory "foo" so that the end result should be:

```
"path/to/dir/foo/subA" 
"path/to/dir/foo/subB"
"path/to/dir/foo/subC"
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is this for a one-off thing or is it going to receive the directory names as parameters? Does the directory 'dir' contain any files that should not be moved to the intermediate directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [tempnam](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php), [unlink](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php), [stat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) [mkdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) and [rename](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) functions.

You could use opendir and readdir to loop through the directories and then make /foo, and move each directory one at a time. But there's a simpler way that is also faster.

1. Use tempnam to get a unique name for a temporary file in "path/to".
2. Use stat to get the permissions for "path/to/dir"
3. tempnam creates a file with the unique name. Use unlink to remove this file, and then use mkdir with the result of stat() to create a new directory with the unique temporary name returned by tempnam
4. use rename to move "path/to/dir" into "path/to/tempdir/foo"
5. use rename to change "path/to/tempdir" to "path/to/dir"